# Creating Cron Task to kill stalled/failed runs in a system

Tags: find, cron, kill

I was given a task to create a `cron` which finds, kills and clears old `puppet` runs that were not successfully installed.

I am more or less looking for a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS IS NOT PORTABLE TO SOLARIS**

In your cron job:

```
if [[ "$(uname)" = "Linux" ]];then killall --older-than 30m,1h puppet;fi
```

Do not attempt to run this or write this on Solaris systems. If you have Solaris systems in your infrastructure as a mixed Linux/Solaris environment, just walk away from this answer entirely.

The man pages have more documentation on the date format for killall, if you're running GNU userland.